# What type of date is returned from Twitter's API?

Tags: datetime, twitter

If I post a tweet on `08/04/2011 at 9:30AM CDT`, the API returns `Thu Aug 04 14:19:12 +0000 2011`, which translates to `08/04/2011 at 2:19pm`. That value is not PDT, and the server I call the API from is in EDT, but none of those match the returned time. I've tried converting to from UTC to my locale, but that didn't seem to matter.

Comment: It's UTC.  The +0000 is an HHMM offset from UTC/GMT.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305826/what-does-0000-mean-in-the-context-of-a-date-returned-by-the-twitter-api/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not UTC?  It's UTC is 6 hours ahead of CST and 5 hours ahead of CDT. So the five hour difference is correct in August.

I'd blame the remaining 11 minutes difference on server time on your side, on Twitter's side, or both...