# What does +0000 mean in the context of a date returned by the twitter API?

Tags: json, date, twitter, iso

This:

```
"Tue Jan 12 21:33:28 +0000 2010"
```

was returned from Twitter's API.  The rest are fairly obvious, but what does +0000 refer to? Is it some type of denotation of a timezone?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This does denote timezone.  It is the offset from UTC time.

Answer (score 14):

`+0000` is an `HHMM` offset from UTC/GMT, and in this case the time you're getting back is exactly UTC.

Note that this doesn't exactly map to a "geographical" time zone, since daylight savings time may change the offset. For example, Sweden is +0100 in the winter and +0200 in summer.

Comment: Do you know if it ever returns dates *not* exactly in UTC?

Comment: @adlwalrus I've only seen UTC times, but since the time zone is there in the reply, I suspect it's "subject to change at any time" or maybe even depending on which API/version you're calling.

Comment: It could just be for ISO-compliance or something, though.