# Time formatting

Tags: php, timestamp

I am currently showing the latest tweet on a site im building and now also adding the latest facebook status from a page.

Received from twiter obj timestamp is formatted like so:

`Tue Feb 08 11:29:36 +0000 2011`

To keep consistency across both, I also want to format the facebook timestamp to display the same.

My question being, what is the `+0000 2011` on the twitter timestamp as I'm trying to format the fb timestamp but am not getting the correct results (i think).

`<?php echo date("D M y h:i:s Z", strtotime($status_ob->timestamp)); ?>`

returns

`Fri Sep 12 09:08:03 7200`

Is this correct or am I missing something.

regards.

Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the format you're looking for.

```
<?php echo date("D M d h:i:s O Y", strtotime($status_ob->timestamp)); ?>
```

`O` will give you the GMT offset and `Y` will give you the long year.
I've also changed your `y` for a `d` as you had a year instead of a day.

Answer (score 2):

> "My question being, what is the +0000 2011 on the twitter timestamp "

I believe the +0000 to be the timezone.

Comment: actually, +0000 is time offset because it doesn't say which time zone it is, just time difference comparing w/ GMT/UTC ;)

Answer (score 2):

> "My question being, what is the +0000 2011 on the twitter timestamp "

[What does +0000 mean in the context of a date returned by the twitter API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305826/what-does-0000-mean-in-the-context-of-a-date-returned-by-the-twitter-api)

Its Time zone