# Looking to extract time zones from tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm having issues gathering the timezones for specific tweets using Tweepy. When I look at all of the contents of each tweet, I find this:

```
... u'created_at': u'Wed Aug 18 02:56:24 +0000 2010', u'contributors_enabled': False, u'time_zone': u'Pacific Time (US & Canada)', ...
```

`tweet.created_at` yields the time but `tweet.time_zone` does not which seems odd to me.

Also, my goal is to organize every tweet within the past few months by date/time. Before I do that, I want to make sure all of the tweets are in the same time zone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+0000` in `tweet.created_at` means that the time being returned is already converted to standard time--the `+0000` is the offset from UTC ([Coordinated Universal Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)).

This is, as far as I know, the standard for tweets returned from the Twitter API (see 
[What does +0000 mean in the context of a date returned by the twitter API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305826/what-does-0000-mean-in-the-context-of-a-date-returned-by-the-twitter-api)
) for more details. This means, unless the API changes, that you don't have to do any sort of conversion to standardize the time between all of your tweets. If you wanted local time information, however, you would have to do the conversion.