# How to deal with "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS +0000" format in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, datetime-format

I have two columns, **DATE_A** and **DATE_B**.
I need to find how much time is between the two dates.
Usually, I would use **JULIANDAY()** and subtract one date from another, but the output is null because of the "**+0000**" part.

Below you'll find an example of values contained in the two columns:

DATE_A - '2022-05-12 00:16:17.553 +0000'

DATE_B - '2022-06-02 00:02:01.158 +0000'

Please tell me what '**+0000**' means and how can I find the time elapsed between the two dates.

Comment: This explains `+0000` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305826/what-does-0000-mean-in-the-context-of-a-date-returned-by-the-twitter-api It looks like you need to convert it to a format SQLite expects: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: Is it always `+0000` at the end? If not post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+0000` is the [offset from UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) this time represents in hours and minutes. For example, here in the US Pacific it's daylight savings time and we're 7 hours behind UTC so we're -0700. `2022-05-12 08:00:00+0000` and `2022-05-12 01:00:00-0700` are the same point in time.

SQLite will accept a slightly different format. There has to be the `:` separator between hours and minutes.

```
2022-05-12 00:16:17.553 +00:00
                           ^
```

You'll have to change the format. Use your programming language's date and time functions.

See "Time Values" in [SQLite Date and Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for valid formats.